# Send Bootstrap Tab's ID to View.py via Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, bootstrap-tabs

I am trying to send tabs id to the the server from Django template. I want to send the selected tab's ID after submit the page. Is there any way to do that? Or How can I put my id into my url? Thank you in advance.

**Here is my tab list:**

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"˛id="myTab">
                    <li><a href="#Section1" role="tab" id="MyFirstTab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>MyFirstTab</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Section2" role="tab" id="MySecondTab"data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>MySeconfTab</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascript (jQuery) to append the current tab ID to the form before it is submitted to the server.  Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var currentTabID = $("ul#myTab li.active a").attr('id');
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: 'currentTabID',
            value: currentTabID
        }).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

Then, in your Django view, you can access that data via `request.POST.get("currentTabID")`

Comment: Unfortunately I got `None` result form the `currentTabID`

Comment: Ah, that's because the id is stored in the <a> tag not the  <li> tag.  I adjusted my answer above. Also, you have a period in your HTML before "id" in the <ul> tag; you should remove that.

Comment: I got `None` again. Unfortunately in my url I got the following result: `?start_date=2018-01-01&end_date=2018-01-05&id=1&currentTabID=` So the `currentTabID`  not sent to the server side.

Comment: Can you verify var currentTabID has a value? Also, verify the form data by  printing `console.log($(this).serializeArray());` so you can see the data the form has prior to submission.

Comment: I check the data, I got the section (let's say #Section3) in my console If if I press ctr+F5 hard refresh, without this I do not get this result. Moreover If the console printed the result, I do not get back from the server.

Comment: Remind me why you are pressing ctr+F5?  This will only work if you click the submit button for the form.  On submit, it creates a hidden input with your desired data, then, appends it to the end of the form so it is included in POST data. If I'm not mistaken, URL parameters are stored in request.GET data.